# Move method to new file and keep it in the same class(make it partial)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, refactoring, resharper

I have a lot of classes with several methods.
And i need to separate each method of the class in its own file, but kept they in the same class( make it partial).

Exploring the R# 6.1 options i haven't found linear possibility. May be there are hidden options?

Thanks

Added:

This refactoring is not usual because this code is UI tests, that grouped in class by the part of functionality. 
We need to separate them to be able to work on them separately from source control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using ReSharper 5.1 and do not know such refatoring in one step.

The fastest way I know is:

1. Create partial classes
   Write a second declaration of partial class with empty body and copy/paste or
   double (Ctl+D) it so often as the count of different files should be.
2. Create files
   Go to every class declaration, press *Ctrl+Shift+R* and select *Move To Another File...*,
   enter a new file name and press *OK*.
3. Move methods
   Do for every method to move: Go to method, press *Alt+Enter*,
   select *Move declaration(s) to another type part* and select file.